# Add a custom IFileProvider to RazorViewEngineOptions that depends on another DI service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I want to add a custom `IFileProvider` to `RazorViewEngineOptions`, however the custom `IFileProvider` requires another service that has been registered with the dep-injection system. However within `ConfigureServices` one doesn't have access to the services yet (as it hasn't been built yet). Eg...

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ... add a bunch of services ...

    services.AddSingleton<SomeService>(); // Note that SomeService depends further on other services.

    services.AddMvc();

    services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
    {
        var instanceOfSomeServiceSingleton = ???How???;

        var myCustomFileProvider = new MyCustomFileProvider(instanceOfSomeServiceSingleton);

        options.FileProviders.Add(myCustomFileProvider);
    });

    // ...
}
```

In the above code I don't know how to get the **instanceOfSomeServiceSingleton**. I could do `services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<SomeService>()` but from my understanding that would build an entirely separate collection of services than the one the rest of the app would be using - which seems bad.

I can build the SomeService manually (and the services that it depends on) and then add them all manually to the services collection, allowing me to have a reference to the SomeService instance within ConfigureServices - but this seems kinda messy. I guess the Configure callback is done before/during services build and so cant have a ref to the services collection itself? So maybe there is no solution?

Thanks for any assistance/insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference [Use DI services to configure options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2#use-di-services-to-configure-options-1)

With that you just need to refactor your starup accordingly

```
//...

services
    .AddOptions<RazorViewEngineOptions>()
    .Configure<SomeService>((options, instanceOfSomeServiceSingleton) => { //<-- instance here

        var myCustomFileProvider = new MyCustomFileProvider(instanceOfSomeServiceSingleton);

        options.FileProviders.Add(myCustomFileProvider);
    });

//...
```